# Does firebird support transactional schema changes?

Tags: firebird

Does firebird support transactional schema changes?  It seems to me that MySQL does not (am I correct?).

Comment: Re: MySQL - see Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html

Comment: When you say "transactional", you mean that you can roll the change back?

Comment: if you're looking for a rdbms that allows schema changes in transactions, take a look at postgresql as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was going to post a simple 'Yes', but StackOverflow does not accept answers with less than 15 characters.
In short: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is, yes, but sometimes you have to commit part of the metadata changes to do other metadata changes and you cannot do any data changes on new-but-not-yet-committed metadata.